Is there a "expand selection to the left/right" in VS Code?
VS Code has a feature to expand/shrink selection. This allows you to, say, quickly select the current statement and keep expanding the selection to the current code block, then the current function etc.
Eclipse's equivalent is called "Expand Selection To", but it also allows expanding the selection to the "next" and "previous" elements. E.g. if you are currently selecting a function in a file, you can expand the selection to include the next (or previous) function in that file.
Is this supported in any way in VS Code?
